# hidding script variables in the main html before passing it to js external file

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Please I have a little challenge, I am working on a web app, I want to pass in an id from the main php file to the javascript external file.
when i inspect element, the id shows`<script> let questId = btoa(<?php echo $_SESSION['questionId']; ?>); </script>`

when i inspect element, i see the actual id which is wrong, even with the btoa function to encrypt the number from displaying.

Please is there a better way of using php directly on js because i want to use the id to fetch info from the database.
Thanks.

Comment: When you say it is wrong, what is it displaying, and what did you expect it to be? Also, did you look over at the console tab to see what javascript fatal errors may be present (given the lack of quotes around the value, I expect there to be one).

Comment: If you are more concerned with 'people seeing the value' by simply inspecting the html, then you will have a real hard time trying to hide that from crafty individuals. Even an ajax call to get that value, can be inspected on the client browser.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I have moved on with it that way,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have an incorrect premise! You cannot hide things from the client if the client needs them.

You may find you can generate some intermediate key (perhaps just adding a salt and hashing the real key), which represents the real key in a mapping which is not presented to the client.